# Activate Features step failed when deploying a workflow

Tags: workflow, 2013, error

I`m about to start to develop workflows in VS2012 for Sharepoint2013. Creating a workflow works fine. The HistoryList and Tasklist are created as well. Now, when I want to depoy my new workflow i receive a really annoying error:

[image: workflow error]

Solution explorer:

[image: solution explorer]

Does anyone know a solution for this ?

thx so far.

**Edit:**

Manifest of the feature:

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Id="5a502a99-9f12-4eda-81b6-ae3cd5376359" ReceiverAssembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" ReceiverClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWorkflowPackageFeatureReceiver" Scope="Web" Title="Workflows Feature1">
  <ActivationDependencies>
    <ActivationDependency FeatureId="2c63df2b-ceab-42c6-aeff-b3968162d4b1" />
  </ActivationDependencies>
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="InnovationProcess\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="InnovationProcess\Workflow.xaml" />
    <ElementFile Location="InnovationProcess\ItemAddedAssociation" />
    <ElementManifest Location="WorkflowHistoryList\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="WorkflowTaskList\Elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Comment: Did you guys find any solution to the problem? I have the same error. On checking further, I noticed that this comes when we are specifically deploying the Workflow task list feature in the workflow package. Any help?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but here is my solution:

After trying to solve this error we decided to re-setup the whole server. However, I am still working on the setups and configuration. But, I'm very confident for on this try, everything till now, installed without any error messages (which was in my recent approaches not usual...)

Answer (score 1):

Please add your feature manifest to the question. You find it by double clicking your feature and at the top select "Manifest".

From your warnings it seems like the feature manifest is corrupt. An easy fix should be to recreate the feature and readd your project items to it.

Also there is a warning about using different version of an assembly. Make sure that you always reference the "15" versions of SharePoint dll:s.

It could also be that one of your references is in turn referencing a version of a dll that is targeted to a different .Net version. See this post for help with troubleshooting that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217114/found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assembly-mvc3

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The feature was auto generated, I did not do anything to it.
Refer to the Assembly or References: Is it really possible to add all from the 15 folder? For example Microsoft.activitis is from `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Workflow Manager\1.0\Microsoft.Activities.dll`

Comment: I would add them from Assemblies -> Extensions in VS, but as you say, that one really just has the 1.0 version. I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks.
So I removed the microsoft.activities reference and replaced it with `Microsoft.Acitivities.Extensions`. This is the new one -> the error disappeared. But the error Àctivate Feature`is still present... As I said, the Features are auto-generated, so I don not know, how I should recreate it.

Comment: Great. To create a new feature, just right click on features and select "Add feature". But if you no longer have any warnings the problem may be elsewhere. http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.se/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager.html is a guid to installing and conf. Workflow Manager

Comment: Thanks again :D
Workflowmangaer is installed and works as well. I can create and publish workflows in sharepointdesigner without any errors. It's really strange... I give you an upvode for your effords

Comment: This might be the dummest advice so far, but try just restarting VS, sometimes it helps in this situations

Comment: doesnt work :(
Somewhere I read about an issue with the linking of the history and tasklist to the workflow. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Sorry to tell you, Workflows is not my strong side (that's why I have mainly giving you some general tips)